# Creating an SDL2 Window in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, sdl

As a challenge I am trying to make a game in assembly. After some research, I tried making a SDL2 window by importing functions from the SDL dynamic library.

```
extern SDL_Init
extern SDL_CreateWindow
extern SDL_Delay
extern SDL_DestroyWindow
extern SDL_Quit

section .bss
    window resb 8

section .text
    global Start
Start:
    push 32 ; This is SDL_INIT_VIDEO
    call SDL_Init
    push 0
    push 800 ; Height
    push 800 ; Width
    push 500 ; y pos
    push 500 ; x pos
    push title ; title
    call SDL_CreateWindow
    mov [window], rax

    push 5000
    call SDL_Delay

    push window
    call SDL_DestroyWindow

    call SDL_Quit

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 1
    int 0x80
    
section .data
    title db "ASM SDL2", 0x0A, 0x00
```

Here I simply initialise SDL, create a window, delay for 5 seconds and quit the window. However when I compile it, absolutely nothing happens.

Here is my `Makefile`

```
LIBS = kernel32.dll ntdll.dll kernelbase.dll msvcrt.dll SDL2.dll

all:
    nasm main.asm -f win64 -o main.obj
    GoLink /files /console main.obj $(LIBS)
```

Since I am on Windows, I use a linker called GoLink. GoLink's entry point is `Start`.
I've even tried this on Linux (WSL), but the results were all the same.

Comment: Your code uses 32 bit calling conventions while you assemble and link it as 64 bit code.  That doesn't match.  Either assemble and link as 32 bit code or write 64 bit code.

Comment: Even if assembled for 64 bit, I still have acess to 32 bit registers. So it doesn't really change the output. Anyhow, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: 64 bit mode has different calling conventions, different system calls, and different data structure layouts.  Attempts to use 32 bit conventions to interface with 64 bit libraries will fail.  It's not a matter of access to registers.

Comment: @AnirudhYamunanGovindarajan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions . But aside that - there is no guarantee that CreateWindow+Delay will produce visible window. You usually have to spin event loop (e.g. SDL_PumpEvents) after creating a window.

Comment: EAX=1 / `int 0x80` is a Linux exit system call.  That won't work on Windows.